# Working Hashcat Syntax

Tags: passwords, hash, hashcat

I want to crack a hash where the cleartext contains:

- starts with a capital letter
- the next 8 or less than 8 small letters
- then 5 or less than 5 numbers
- and ends with ! (exclamation mark)

I want to use a brute force attack.

So please give me a proper syntax for this asap.

Comment: you create a password file using a bash script to iterate through what you specified, then feed that file to hashcat

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple: `?u?l?l?l?l?l?l?l?l?d?d?d?d?d!`

Reference: [Hashcat: Mask Attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if the small numbers are 8 or less than 8, and what if the numbers are 5 or less than 5. Please answer me asap.

Comment: If you don't want to check all numbers 0-9 you can define a custom character set, example: -1 012345 and then use ?1 instead of ?d. For example: -1 012345 ?u?l?l?l?l?l?l?l?l?1?1?1?1?1!